# AFNetworking Data Parameter is nil JSON Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I have an UITableViewController and I'm trying getting JSON data from url with this code but I'm getting error.What should I do ?

```
  AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
        [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

        NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://testurl.com/api/index.php"];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"process":@"search_customer",@"page": @""};
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

        [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

        [manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:string];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
            self.customerCards = [NSMutableArray array];
            NSArray *customersArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"musteri_list"];
            for (NSDictionary *customersDictionary in customersArray) {
                ApiClass *customer = [ApiClass customersWithTitle:[customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adi"]];
                customer.tel = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"tel"];

                [self.customerCards addObject:customer];
            }

            NSLog(@"GET: %@", string);
            NSLog(@"POST: %@", parameters);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

This is the error bloc

```
2015-03-26 14:27:37.656 SaphiraCrm[13770:3881729] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

Comment: You assume [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"musteri_list"]; exists. If you don't have a valid dataDictionary all the code under that line will cause crash. So verify if string, jsonData, dataDictionary etc are valid before start use for loop conditions.

Comment: Also why don't you use the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` to get the JSON directly.

Comment: Try to debug it using breakpoints and check exactly where it is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I figured Out how can I do this.

There is my code

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/api/index.php"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"process":@"search_customer",@"page": @""};
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

        self.customerCards = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *customersArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"musteri_list"];
        NSLog(@"%@",customersArray);
        for (NSDictionary *customersDictionary in customersArray) {
            ApiClass *customer = [ApiClass customersWithTitle:[customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adi"]];
            customer.tel = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"tel"];

            [self.customerCards addObject:customer];

        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"GET: %@", string);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in the fact that you are treating the `responseObject` as if it was `NSData`, but according to `AFNetworking` [examples](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#http-request-operation-manager), by default `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`'s `responseSerializer` is an `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, so `responseObject` is already a parsed JSON represented as an `NSDictionary` (depends on the serializer).

Therefore, the line

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

returns `nil`, which causes the next line

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:string];
```

to raise the exception.

I would suggest that you check `responseObject` is what you expect it to be and refactor your code accordingly.

```
...

[manager POST:urlPath 
   parameters:parameters 
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          if (responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"Response is a %@ and contains: %@", [responseObject class], responseObject);
              // Process responseObject according to its type

...
```

**Note:**
It is very likely that the above is just the consequence of a previous mistake in the way you set your seriliazer's configuration, since you set first the `acceptableContentType` first and then overwrite it with the default one.

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
...
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]; 
// this is likely to invalidate the previous, since you overwritting
// the manager's serializer with a new one with default configuration.
```